# Push Notification using Telerik AppBuilder with Microsoft Windows Azure

Tags: azure, push-notification, telerik, azure-notificationhub, telerik-appbuilder

I'm trying to use Windows Azure Push Notifications with Telerik Platform App Builder, but I'm having issue where notifications never arrived to the targeted devices, after they registered successfully to the Azure Notification hub.

I create a Github project to show my code https://github.com/owidat/Telerik_AppBuilder_Azure_PushNotification

I Also 
used Microsoft 
Service Bus Explorer to make sure that devices are registered (which they are), but I keep seeing the following error:

Exception: A certificate with thumbprint 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' cannot be found.

Which is related to the .p12 Cryptographic Identity, but I'm not sure that this is the problem and I tried to recreate the .p12 and re upload it to Azure portal but the same Exception keep coming with the Microsoft Service Bus Explorer. Also I'm not sure that this is the problem because test push notifications are not hitting the Android and windows devices too.

Till this point I do not know how to find the issue and resolve it.

So please can anyone help me?

Comment: For push notifications to work with Android you don't use a certificate.  You use your GCM API Key.  Has that been setup properly in Azure?  iOS uses the certificate file and you have to make sure you use a certificate that is generated specifically for Apple PNS.  You can't use the same certificate that you used to sign the app.  It is a different type of certificate.